# Django - How to declare variable in template depending on condition

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to do something really basic but against all odds it seems like it's not as easy as it should be.

I need to transcribe the following into django template syntax :

```
p = '&' if '?' in request.path else '?'
```

All I found so far to create variable is the **with** statement but I can't get what I need :

```
{% if '?' in request.path %}
    {% with p='&' %}{% endwith %}
{% else %}
    {% with p='?' %}{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

p needs to be available in all the template, and since I use a condition here, I can't afford to duplicate the html structure twice to put it inside the with statement.

It has to be an easy way to do this that I'm missing...

Comment: You can use a template tag/filter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Unfortunately that doesn't help me much if I don't know what to do exactly

Comment: `request.path` will __never__ contain "?" as that character represents the start of the query string (GET parameters) and is not part of the path

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for the tip but the condition itself doesnt really matter, I need to find a way to declare a variable using whatever condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one knows so I created a custom tag in my app to perform something that should be straight forward... :

```
@register.simple_tag
def define(val=None):
    return val
```

And in my view :

```
{% load custom_tags %}
    {% if '?' in new_partial_url %}
      {% define "&" as p %}
    {% else %} 
      {% define "?" as p %}
    {% endif %}
```